# how to get java output in html file directly?

Tags: selenium

I need a technique for selenium that can run my java code(Test case) and send java console output directly to  a html file like a report of the all test cases result, where in the html file we can see output in simplified way.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 2):

use extentreporter for selenium webdriver reporting

visit this link for getting full details

http://relevantcodes.com/extentreports-for-selenium/

Comment: Thanks, but I am just curious to know that, is it not possible to do the same by coding rather than what you suggests above.

Comment: In this you also have to do the coding to get the actual output. It is just providing you the library.

Comment: If u want to do everything at your own then you should read the code of these reporters. These reporters are open source. You will get the code easily.